# webview having trouble with redirects

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest

```
NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlString];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[self.webview loadRequest:requestObj];
```

The UIWebView is having trouble with redirects. How can I make sure the uiwebview handles redirects properly?

Comment: what do you mean by redirects?

Comment: a url like linkedin.com/view?id=lbee that redirects to linkedin.co/view?id=1222

Comment: @BamBam : Did you include `http://` or `https://` to the urladdress .It is necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do a redirect from one site to another, just load your website, but add a BOOL var for checking if the right page is loaded.

```
 BOOL page1Loaded;
```

then, if you need to change to another site, just create a global NSString var like so

```
 // for site name
 NSString *urlAddress;
```

and just update upon needing to

```
 if(page1Loaded) {

    // as seen in @Lithu T.V.'s comment, DO NOT FORGET the http:// or https://
    // name of address 
    urlAddress = @"http://..." or @"https://..."

    NSString *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlString];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [self.webview loadRequest:requestObj];
 }
 else {

    // as seen in @Lithu T.V.'s comment, DO NOT FORGET the http:// or https://
    // name of redirect 
    urlAddress = @"http://..." or @"https://..." 

    NSString *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlString];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [self.webview loadRequest:requestObj];
 }
```

hope this helps!